# Problem in installing matplot library using conda

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create new environments and to install the necessary package. However, when I try to install Matplot lib, I am getting the following error `InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive C:\\Users\\X\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\openssl-1.1.1h-he774522_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCould not unlink')`. I tried to use `conda clear -a` to remove all files and then try to install matplotlib using `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib` but getting the same error.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting that file? or at least moving it to a backup location?

Comment: what statement did you use to install matplotlib/

Comment: Are you trying to install the package in a new/clean environment?